# Remove string after expected value

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine

I'm writing a short script that compares the OS running on our VM's against what we have manually entered into our CMDB. Below is some test code

```
foreach ($r in $SQL) {
  if ((Get-VMGuest $r.name).OSFullName -eq $r.OS) {
    Write-Host "Match"
  } else {
    Write-Host "Not matching"
  }
}
```

Here is some example output

```
VM Output = Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Standard (32-bit)
SQL Output = Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Standard Edition

VM Output = Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)
SQL Output = Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Standard
```

Since the way the result is outputted i never get a match even though the OS are the same.

Is there a way to break off after the Server year or another way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to try and normalise the two strings and then compare the normalised versions; this function is a start which you can adapt to your particular situation:

```
function NormalizeOS([string]$RawOs) {
  $output = $RawOs -Replace 'Edition', '' `
   -Replace ',', '' `
   -Replace '(64-bit)', '' `
   -Replace '(32-bit)', '';

  return $output.trim();
}
```

You can then adapt your original `if` statement:

```
if (NormalizeOS((Get-VMGuest $r.name.OSFullName)) -eq NormalizeOS($r.OS))
```

The technique here is to try and strip out the irrelevant information from both strings leaving only the details you care about.

Comment: Yeah thats eacly what i'm trying to accomplish. Your function runs fine however the if statement wont, the NormalizeOS($r.OS)) part wont work, is there a parenthesis missing or something?

Comment: Hmm, yes the parenthesis were in the wrong place, give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string using a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

To exactly follow your definition *"break off after the Server"*:

```
($r.OS -Split "(?<=\WServer\W)")[0]
```

Comment: I actaully meant the server year/version but it didnt show up since i wrote it inside <>. Original post has been updated

Comment: In that case you probably want something like: `($r.OS -Split "(?<=\WServer \d\d\d\d\W)")[0]`

Comment: or if you just want to get everything up till anything that isn't a word character or a space: (like a comma or a left-parenthesis):  `($r.OS -Split "[^\w ]")[0]`